# Java: How to access implementation of a method of Sub class from Super class

Tags: java, inheritance

I needed to understand this, now that I have figured this out, I thought I should put it out there, might help someone:

How to access implementation of a method provided by subclass inside super class?

Consider a situation that you are implementing a method in a class that will eventually be extended by other classes. Your class needs information that will only be available after a sub class has provided it at runtime. How do you use a method that will be available at runtime?

Comment: To write a good self answer, a good question is in order. I recommend that you [edit] your question to make up to standards

Comment: Even self-answered questions have to conform to the [ask] rules. The question has to explain the problem, give short example code etc. It's unclear what the relationship between your answer, your question, and your title really is.

Comment: That's just a repeat of the title. What you need to do is **explain the problem**. What type of access? Why do you need to access the implementation? What situation got you to need to understand this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Consider following:**

```
public interface Animal {

    bool isVertebrate();
    bool isDomesticable();  
}
```

and an abstract class that implements this interface:

```
abstract class Cat implements Animal {

public bool isVertebrate() {return true;}

public void dealWithCat(){
if (isDomesticable()){
 ...
   }
}
```

But implementation for `isDomesticable` is delegated to subclass:

```
public class Tiger extends Cat {

public bool isDomesticable(){
return false;
}
```

Since Cat is `abstract`, it can't be instantiated. It is free to provide implementation for some interface methods, but doesn't have to provide it for every method. The methods that it doesn't provide implementation for, must be provided by by subclass. And at run time, methods in super class get implementation from subclass. So in our example, implementation of `isDomesticable()` is not provided by Cat but it is later implemented by Tiger.